# Convert multipe columns to 1 column and multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to change an excel database sort order.
There is a sheet like this: (t means type)

```
T1-Weight  T1-Height   T1-Work   T2-Weight    T2-Height T2-Work

  1.             15           20           5          25           40        30
  2.             35           12           20          7           89        63
```

there is like hundred thousands of lines in this sheet with this structure and I want to write a macro to rebuild its whole structure like this:
and I want to change it like this:

[image: soreadsheet]

Actually I want to create a column to save type of data in each record .
right now type of data is saved right before it’s row’s head name (T1-Height) but I want to change it like above picture.
I know it will multiply records number by types count(which is 2) but I have to do it

Answer (score 1):

Insert a column before the first column on your spreadsheet.  Enter T1 in the first row and fill down.

Starting at column C (T2-Weight), highlight the data in C, D, and E, cut it, and paste it at the bottom of your T1 data.

Using your new column, enter T2 in the first row of that data and fill down.

Repeat as necessary.